# Update an Optional element to protobuffer

Tags: r, protocol-buffers

I'm using R for coding. I need to add/update an optional field in my protobuffer files. The function "add" works well for repeated fields; but it does not seem to be compatible for optional fields.

example:

```
A$add("gender", X["gender"]); # Works if A is repeated; but not when it's optional!
```

Do you know what function I should use for this purpose?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting a question, it's helpful to include a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) showing exactly how you created your objects, and the behavior your expect. Be sure to explicitly list all non-standard libraries needed to run the sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

If "add" does not work, you should try:

```
A$gender = X["gender"];
```

Should work!
Thanks

Comment: Check this tip as answer, after a while.

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
A$set("gender", X["gender"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The optional field already exists. You only need to assign a value to it.